# How to override a parameter value inside a python script from Airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

I have python script `aws_test.py` which I am calling through airflow `ESCoperator` I have parameter  called `instance` inside the .py script which I want override using airlfow dag.How can this be done.

**Value to passed from the DAG to the .py scriptto override**

instance ='ins12'

**My current Airflow DAG code**

```
dag = DAG(
    'execute_sample_job',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    max_active_runs=1
)

set_input_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='set_params',
    python_callable=set_input,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)

execute = ECSOperator(
    task_id='execute',
    launch_type='FARGATE',
    task_definition=Helpers.get_param('task_def'),
    cluster="ds-notebooks",
    awslogs_group=Helpers.get_param('awslogs_group'),
    awslogs_stream_prefix=Helpers.get_param('awslogs_stream_prefix'),
    network_configuration={
        'awsvpcConfiguration': {
            'securityGroups': [Helpers.get_param('security_group')],
            'subnets': [Helpers.get_param('subnet1'), Helpers.get_param('subnet2'), Helpers.get_param('subnet3')]
        }
    },
    overrides={
        'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name': 'notebook',
                'environment': [
                    {
                        'name': 'INPUT',
                        'value': 'tasks/python/aws_test.py'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'PARAMETERS',
                        'value': json.dumps(
                            dict(
                                instance='ins12',
                                
                            )
                        )
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    dag=dag)

execute.set_upstream(set_input_task)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the instance name in DagRun conf. For example:

```json
{"instance_name": "fooName"}
```

Then you can [reference it](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) in your `overrides` because it's a template field:

```py
...
'value': '{"instance": "{{ dag_run.conf["instance"] }}"}'
...
```

### EDIT

Or if you generate the instance name in `set_input_task` then do:

```py
    overrides={
        'containerOverrides': [
            {
                'name': 'notebook',
                'environment': [
                    {
                        'name': 'INPUT',
                        'value': 'tasks/python/aws_test.py'
                    },
                    {
                        'name': 'PARAMETERS',
                        'value': '{"instance": "{{ task_instance.xcom_pull["set_input_task"] }}"}'
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
```

In this way you can use XCom to pass them name. This assumes that your `set_input` function returns a string being the instance name.

Comment: were do place this`{"instance_name": "fooName"}` anywhere inside dag cdode

Comment: I am slightly confused. If you show me this overriding in my current code template it would really helpful

Comment: Edited my reply, let me know if it's what you want to do.